# Evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{n}\int_{1}^{n}\frac{x-1}{x+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{n}\int_{1}^{n}\frac{x-1}{x+1}dx$$

My approach is not correct, I think.

I took $f(x)=(x-1)/(x+1)$ which is continuous so there is a $F(x)$ a primitive of f(x) such that $F'(x)=f(x)$

So I used L'Hospital but when I derived, I derived for n which is number, not for x and I think it's not correct.

I obtained $\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{F(n)-F(1)}{n}=\lim_{n \to \infty }f(n)=1$ which is the correct answer but I'm not sure if this is the right method.There's another way to solve this?

Comment: Using L'Hopital's Rule is the natural approach and your answer is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your approach is correct. You applied L'Hôpital's rule to
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty } \frac{F(x) - F(1)}{x} =  \lim_{x\to \infty } \frac{F'(x)}{1} = 1 
$$
which is valid because the denominator $g(x) = x $ on the left-hand side diverges to $ \infty$, satisfies $g'(x) \ne 0$, and the limit on the right-hand side exists.

Then $ \frac{F(x_n) - F(1)}{x_n} \to 1$ for all sequences $(x_n)$ with $x_n \to \infty$, and in particular 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty } \frac{F(n) - F(1)}{n} = 1 \, .
$$

---

As mentioned in [L'Hôpital's rule: General proof (case 2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_proof) this is actually a consequence of the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem): In your case,
$$
 a_n = \int_1^n f(x) \, dx  \, , \, b_n = n 
$$
satisfy the hypotheses of the Stolz–Cesàro theorem with
$$
\begin{align}
 \frac{a_{n+1} - a_n}{b_{n+1} - b_n} &= \int_n^{n+1} f(x) \, dx \\
&= f(\xi_n) \text{ for some } \xi_n \in (n, n+1) \\
&\to 1 \text{ for }n \to \infty \, ,
\end{align}
$$
using the [mean value theorems for integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals). It follows that
$$
 \frac 1n \int_1^n f(x) \, dx  = \frac{a_n}{b_n} \to 1
$$
for $n \to \infty$.

Comment: L'Hospital's Rule applies to the form $\text{anything} /\infty$ so verifying that $F(x) \to\infty $ is not needed.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: You are right, thanks. I have removed that part.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 7):

Usethat $$\frac{x-1}{x+1}=1-\frac{2}{x+1}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help :)